# how can i make two values ​in same column as separate columns in python

Tags: python, dataframe, calculated-columns

```
in this commands;


import requests

import pandas as pd

url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/depth?symbol=BNBUSDT&limit=100"

payload = {}

headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/json'

}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload).json()

depth = pd.DataFrame(response, columns=["bids","asks"])

print(depth)
```

outputs :

| ........ | bids | asks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [382.40000000, 86.84800000] | [382.50000000, 196.24600000] |
| 1 | [382.30000000, 174.26400000] | [382.60000000, 116.10300000] |

and first i need to change the table this format

| ........ | bidsValue | bidsQuantity | asksValue | asksQuantity | rangeTotalbidsQuantity | rangeTotalasksQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 382.40000000 | 86.84800000 | 382.50000000 | 196.24600000 |  |  |
| 1 | 382.30000000 | 174.26400000 | 382.60000000 | 116.10300000 |  |  |

and then **turn the columns values float** so that be able to **calculate in a specific range values quantity** *(e.g 0bidsValue 400.00 and ?bidsValue 380.00 ("?" because of i don't know row number) first i must find row number of bidsValue 380.00 (for example it is 59) then calculate 0bidsQuantity to 59bidsQuantity)* and last **write the results in rangeTotalbidsQuantity column**.

I've been trying for hours, I tried many commands from "pandas.Dataframe" but I couldn't do it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69148256/11457061).
In your case this would look something like this:

```
depth['bidsValue'], depth['bidsQuantity'] = zip(*list(depth['bids'].values))
depth['asksValue'], depth['asksQuantity'] = zip(*list(depth['asks'].values))
depth = depth.drop(columns=['bids', 'asks'])
```

For the second part look at this [tutorial](https://thispointer.com/pandas-add-two-columns-into-a-new-column-in-dataframe/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example:

```
pd.DataFrame(df['bids'].tolist())
```

Then concatenate that to the original dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can `apply()`  `pandas.Series` and assign to new columns

```
depth[ ['bidsValue', 'bidsQuantity'] ] = depth['bids'].apply(pd.Series)
depth[ ['asksValue', 'asksQuantity'] ] = depth['asks'].apply(pd.Series)
```

and later you have to remove original columns `bids,asks`

```
depth = depth.drop(columns=['bids', 'asks'])
```

---

Full working code with other changes

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/depth"

payload = {
    'symbol': 'BNBUSDT',
    'limit': 100,
}

response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
#print(response.status_code)

data = response.json()

depth = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["bids","asks"])

#print(depth)

depth[ ['bidsValue', 'bidsQuantity'] ] = depth['bids'].apply(pd.Series)
depth[ ['asksValue', 'asksQuantity'] ] = depth['asks'].apply(pd.Series)

depth = depth.drop(columns=['bids', 'asks'])

print(depth.to_string())
```